# In Spark Based on priority Storing of Data

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 Data Sets and based on priority I want to store my Data

DataSet 1 ---> Is Detail about my Table

```
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
|   user_id|  rate    |date         | Class    |
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| XO_121   | 10       |2020-04-20   | A       |         
| XO_121   | 20       |2020-04-21   |  B      |         
| XO_121   | 30       |2020-04-22   |    C    |        
| XO_121   |0          |2020-04-23   |       D |       
| XO_123   |10        |2020-04-24   |       B |        
| XO_123   |40         |2020-04-25   |      D  |
```

Dataset 2 ---> List Down Priority of Class

```
+----------- +----------+-
|   Class |  Priority  |
+-----------+----------+-
| A         | 1        |               
| B         |  2       |
| C         | 3      |               
| D         |  4       |            
| E         |  5       |
```

OUTPUT DATASET should be like this

```
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
|   user_id|  rate    |date         | Class    |
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| XO_121   | 10       |2020-04-20   | A       |          
| XO_123   |10         |2020-04-25   |      B  |
```

So I want is to store data which have same `user_id` but different `rate` based on priority table .I have tried my code but it is not working I'm new to Partitioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a join and get the first row in each group:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = df1.join(df2, 'Class').withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('Priority'))
).filter('rn = 1').drop('rn')

result.show()
+-----+-------+----+----------+--------+
|Class|user_id|rate|      date|Priority|
+-----+-------+----+----------+--------+
|    B| XO_123|  10|2020-04-24|       2|
|    A| XO_121|  10|2020-04-20|       1|
+-----+-------+----+----------+--------+
```

You didn't specify your language but in Scala it would be

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = df1.join(df2, "Class").withColumn(
    "rn", 
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("Priority"))
).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")
```